# How to show java plugin console

Tags: java, console, plugins

In windows, when I open a web page containing applet, icon of java plugin console is displayed in systray. But in Ubuntu, I don't find any way to show java plugin console. How can I open java plugin console with FireFox and Chromium in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because the Java Console is hidden by default.

To change this:

1. First start the Java Control Panel.

   From the command line run: `ControlPanel` (if not in PATH, you may have to run something like `/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_51/bin/ControlPanel` )

   Or, choose from the Dash like the screenshot below

   [image: Java Control Panel]
2. In the Java Control Panel go to the Advanced Tab, expand Java Console and choose Show Console. Screenshot below:

   [image: Set the Java Console On]
3. **Now the console will pop up whenever you execute ANY Java Applet.**

Fix INFO from this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/241277).

Comment: I follow your instruction but java plugin console is still not displayed. I use Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Run firefox on the console and try to load an applet. Past the log so we can see whats happening :)

Comment: How to pass the log? Using jconsole, I know that applet is loaded by icedtea plugin and runned on OpenJDK JRE.

Comment: @TranDinhThoai, please switch to sunjdk and try :3. Redirect the browser output to a log file, `firefox` > log

Comment: I don't have a system menu, and I'm using even another distro (not Ubuntu), but I'd like to add that there must be commands one can invoke from shell which do these things. See @josircg's answer below for one variant. Or I've discovered that I have `jcontrol` (and `jconsole`) in my PATH (in my distro). This can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the dash interface (for example if you use Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc), an alternative method is:

1) Open Terminal and type:

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

2) Change Directory to the last directory shown, for example:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/
```

3) Type:

```
./ControlPanel
```

Comment: I have `jcontrol` (and `jconsole`) commands in my PATH. (But it's not Ubuntu, another distro.)

Answer (score 0):

Now `Icedtea` has  its own control panel, type :

```
% /usr/lib/jvm/[YOUR JAVA VERSION]/jre/bin/itweb-settings
```

You can find your java version by typing `ls /usr/lib/jvm/` and the folder should have the format of `java-[VERSION]-openjdk-[ARCHITECTURE]`.

Answer (score 0):

- Environment:

  - Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
  - IcedTea Web 1.8
- Steps to enable the IcedTea console:

  1. Click on the "show applications" icon (bottom left of your screen, by default. The bottom-most item in the launch bar)
  2. Search for "icedTea" (don't worry about lower/upper case)
  3. Click on the IcedTea Control Web Control Panel item, probably the only one found (among other things, it looks like a penguin with a giant red nose).
  4. On the selection list (displayed on the left side), select the option debugging by clicking on it.
  5. At the debugging settings panel, by the bottom left, there is a drop-down whose label says "Java Console" whose option  "Show on startup" is the one you want to select.
  6. Click "Apply" and "OK". You may now close the IcedTea Control Panel.

The expected behavior is that, when you launch an applet, the console will also keep open, in a separate window, of course, logging stuff with a small delay.